# Vim: how to refresh buffer to point to new filepath

Tags: vim, filesystems, nerdtree

I was wondering if it was possible to refresh an open buffer to point to a new path if I've modified it.

Ex:

1. Open `./dest1/foo` in vim
2. Move `foo` to `./dest2/foo`
3. Update open buffer to reflect new path `./dest2/foo` instead of read/writing to old path

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its possible but not without a minor disruption.

1. Open ./dest1/foo in vim
2. Get into vim's command mode by pressing ":"
3. Issue the following command at the prompt-- !mv '%:p' "./dest2/foo"

You may now get a message that 'File "foo" is no longer available. Press ENTER or type command to continue'.  Press ENTER. Vim now re-opens the file from the new location.

Comment: This solution misses point 3 of OP question. If you type `:pwd` the path will still be that of the old file, but should be updated.

Answer (score 2):

The next function does what you need:

```
function Saveas(newfile)                                                 
    let oldfile=expand("%:p")                                            
    silent! exe 'saveas!' fnameescape(a:newfile)                         
    bd #                                                                 
    exe 'cd ' . expand('%:h')                                            
    call delete(oldfile)                                                 
endfunction                                                              
command! -nargs=1 -complete=dir -complete=file Saveas call Saveas('<args>')
```

How to use it: If currently editing `./foo`, you can do `:Saveas ./dest1/foo` (assuming `dest1` directory exists). Now the current buffer will be `./dest/foo` whereas `foo` will be deleted from the buffer list. Also the current directory (`pwd`) will be updated to `./dest`.

**Note**: File `foo` will be removed. A new file `./dest1/foo` with the contents of `foo` will be created.

Comment: Tim Pope's [eunuch.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) provides a similar commands, `:Move` & `:Rename`

Comment: This is useful, but I was actually seeing if there was a way to update the filepath when moving files outside of vim (say I had an open shell and was rearranging some files in a project).